# empty base class optimization

Tags: c++

Two quotes from the C++ standard, §1.8:

> An object is a region of storage.
>
> Base class subobjects may have zero size.

I don't think a region of storage can be of size zero. That would mean that some base class subobjects aren't actually objects. How do these statements co-exist?

Comment: Why do you think a region of storage can't be of size zero? Apparently it can :)

Comment: @bmargulies `malloc` is specifically worded in C so that it doesn't need to create an object of zero size: "If the size of the space requested is zero, the behavior is implementation-deﬁned: either a null pointer is returned, or the behavior is as if the size were some nonzero value"

Comment: @Joh, how about new int[0] in that case? Of course there's some memory there, but you have to act as if it has length 0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A philosophical argument over the definition of "region" is unnecessary.

1.8/5 says, "Unless it is a bit-field, a most derived object shall have a non-zero size ... Base class sub-objects may have zero size".

So the standard is quite clear what objects (and hence what "regions of storage") can have zero size. If you disagree with the standard what "region" means in English that's one thing, you can fault the authors' (non-programming-related) literary skills. For that matter you can fault their poetic skills (14.7.3/7) But it's quite clear what the standard says here about the sizes of objects of class types.

The pragmatic way to read standards is that given two plausible interpretations of a word, choose the one which doesn't directly contradict another sentence in the same section of the standard. Don't choose the one which matches more closely your personal preferred use of the word, or even the most common use.

Comment: "Unless it is a bit-field, a most derived object shall have a non-zero size" seems to conflict with `new int[0]` which is said to "allocate an array with no elements". Does that imply that arrays actually *do* contain internal padding in that case?

Comment: I don't think that an array is a most-derived object. 1.8/4: "If a complete object ... is of class type, it's type is considered the most-derived class ... an object of a most derived class type is called a most derived object"

Comment: @Steve it says "an object of a most derived class type or of a non-class type is called a most derived object". - Edit: C++03 wording seem to differ from the FCD wording.

Comment: @Johannes: not in my copy, although I'm prepared to believe that other versions differ, or even that there's a second conflicting definition of most derived object somewhere else.

Comment: @Steve however i think the intent of C++03 is to include non-class types in the definition "most derived class type", otherwise the prefix "Unless it is a bit-field, ..." prefix would not make sense.

Comment: True, that's a difficult one to resolve. No built-in fundamental type can be of size 0 anyway, because they all must be capable of representing at least 2 values. So it doesn't need stating in 1.8 whether they can be zero size or not. Interesting point about aggregates under the revised definition: is there then a contradiction in C++0x, which C++03 arguably avoided completely by accident?

Comment: Gotta love 14.7.3/7! +1 just for that.

Comment: @Konrad: I don't think I've ever read that part of the standard through, I found it because one day looking up something else I spotted "immolation, self" in the index :-)

Answer (score 10):

C++ does not allow an object of size zero, because every object must have a unique memory address.  So if you have:

```
struct empty {};

// ...

empty myempty;
empty* ptr = &myempty;
```

then `ptr` must be pointing to a unique memory address.  The standard states the minimum size for an object is 1 byte for this purpose.  Similarly, allocations of size 0 are allowed, and return a valid pointer, even if writing to that pointer is not allowed (this works for `malloc(0)`, and `new empty` returns a pointer to one byte, since `sizeof(empty) == 1`).

If I derive from `empty` like so:

```
struct derived : public empty
{
    int data;
}
```

There is no longer any point in the base class `empty` occupying one byte, because all `derived` will have a unique address due to the `data` member.  The quote "Base class subobjects may have zero size" is present to allow, in this case, for the compiler to not use any space for `empty`, such that `sizeof(derived) == 4`.  As the title states, it's just an optimization, and it is perfectly legal for the `empty` part of `derived` to occupy zero space.

Comment: Actually `sizeof(empty)` is allowed to be larger, and most compilers are going to make it at least the machine word width.

Comment: "every object must have a unique memory address" - despite the incorrect wording in the standard, every object is _not_ required to have a unique memory address. An object can can the same address as a subobject at its beginning, and/or a base class subobject. It should say that every _complete_ object must have a unique address.

Comment: additionally *at the same time*, if you delete an object and get a new one it may very well be at the same address :-)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard 1.8.5 states :-

> Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most
>   derived object shall have a non-zero
>   size and shall occupy one or more
>   bytes of storage. **Base class
>   subobjects may have zero size**. An
>   object of trivially copyable or
>   standard-layout type (3.9) shall
>   occupy contiguous bytes of storage.

So, the standard alows a base-class that has no data members (and no virtuals) to share the same address as another subobject with a distinct type. You can play around with the empty base class size like ...

```
struct a{}; 
struct a1{}; 
struct b : public a, public a1{char c;}; 


int main() 
{ 
  std::cout << sizeof(b) << "\n"; 
  std::cout << sizeof(b::a); 
} 


Which outputs (ignoring padding)...

1 
1 


now try: 


struct a{}; 
struct b : public a {a ax;}; 


int main() 
{ 
  std::cout << sizeof(b) << "\n"; 
  std::cout << sizeof(b::a); 
} 


and the output is ...

2 
1
```

because the two instances of a (as a base and as a member) must have distinct addresses.

**BTW**: "b::a" is another way to say "a". The presence of the scope access operator does not request the "base-class subobject of b of type a". Verse `5.3.3/2` says :- *When applying sizeof to a base class subobject, the result is the size of that object's type*.