# Data type for bool in LLVM IR

Tags: c++, c++11, llvm, llvm-clang

I'm writing a programming language compiler to integrate DSLs and C/C++. For that I have decided for LLVM for a couple of reasons.

There is a main program. In this main program I load bitcode files, which were compiled by clang. The loadable bitcode file represents a short, but complete programming language environment with REPL, parser, linker and AST.

My understanding so far was that boolean datatypes are represented in IR as i1. I have optimized my code with -O3 and I get for a boolean following IR code (by disassembling with llvm-dis from the generated bitcode file):

```
%"class.tl::contrib::toy::ToyREPL" = type <{  %"class.tl::contrib::toy::InitLanguage"*, i8, [7 x i8] }>
```

The class is ToyREPL and it is using another class InitLanguage. Oddly, the boolean seems to be presented by an i8 and an array of i8. I don't really get it.

I have defined a Makefile. First I compile the files. Afterwards I link them to a bc file, then optimize and link it with some other libs.

```
@cd $(BIN)/$(TARGET)/$(2); $(LINK) -o $(1).$(BITCODE_EXT) $(3)

@cd $(BIN)/$(TARGET)/$(2); $(OPT) -O3 $(1).$(BITCODE_EXT) -o $(1).$(OPT_NAME).$(BITCODE_EXT) $(OPTIMIZER_FLAGS) 

@$(LINK) -o $(BIN)/$(TARGET)/$(2)/$(1).$(BITCODE_EXT) $(BIN)/$(TARGET)/$(2)/$(1).$(OPT_NAME).bc $(LINK_OPTION) $(4)
```

Compiler flags are:

```
-v -g -emit-llvm -I$(BOOST_INC_DIR) -std=c++11 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
```

Optimizer flags are `-std-link-opts`

Link flag is `-v`.

The relevant part of the Class ToyREPL is here:

```
class ToyREPL {
private:

  InitLanguage *initLang;

  bool runs = false;
```

**Now my question:** Is my assumption wrong bool should be bitcode compiled to i1? What kind of compiler switch I need to consider to compile to i1? Let me know if you think my build process is wrong in some way. The generate bitcode file is readable and I can retrieve the module and the class ToyREPL as a StructType.

Comment: Replaced quotes with code -- quotes are usually best when quoting stuff intended for humans to write, not computers.  ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your question is essentially - why was the C++ class

```
class ToyREPL {
  bool runs = false;
  ...
};
```

Compiled by Clang into `type <{ i8, [7 x i8], ... }>`?

So first of all, why Clang chose `i8` over `i1` for a boolean field is straightforward - [the smallest C++ type takes one byte of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29684487/242762), and unless you use bit-fields, that also applies to fields in structs. Also see [this related question about *why* a whole byte is used for booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4626815/242762). LLVM itself uses `i1` for boolean values, but that's because it's roughly platform-independent - in the lowering phase those might become whole bytes again.

As for `[7 x i8]`, that's padding, made to ensure every object of this type is 64-bit aligned and does not share its memory with any other object - very reasonable approach on a 64-bit system. Alternatively, if there's a following struct field, the padding might have been inserted to ensure that field is 64-bit aligned.

[The Wikipedia article on alignment and padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) is a useful starting point if you want to know more.

Comment: This seems like the obvious answer... but is there no exception on LLVM's side or is most of it caused by just the way C++ is specified?

Comment: Thanks. The paddings make sense as I have a 64 bit machine. But this means I can never discern between an integer value and a boolean only if I have the bitcode at hand, isn't it?

Comment: @VermillionAzure this is all coming from Clang, as far as I know, due to the way C++ is specified and for performance reasons. For instance, another language may mandate `i1` for booleans to save space - but then the lowering phase might do funky things in order to load and store an `i1` on a machine that only has byte addressing.

Comment: @repl You can discern looking at *how* it's used... but in general I guess you're right and there's no way to tell. If it's important for you you can always turn on debugging information, that should provide all the information about the declared type of each field.